# What is the default browser form behavior for POST method?

Tags: html, go, post, browser

Normally I use JSON API and SPA for when I make web apps, but I am trying to learn how to use the more simple method server-side templating and default form behavior with Go.

I am doing something very similar to what is seen [here](https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/en/04.1.html). The only difference is that I changed the `action` to `"/"` in the form for simplicity and handle the GET and POST from the same Handler (filtering by method type).

Server-Side Template

```
<form action="/" method="post"   >

         ...

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="myname">Dev Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="myname" name="myname" value="{{.MyDname}}">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </form>
```

Server side

```
func MainPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) //get request method
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, err := template.New("RTL Page").Parse(page)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = t.Execute(w, State)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    if r.Method == http.MethodPost {
        r.ParseForm()
        ...
    }
}
```

The initial web page renders fine, the data gets sent correctly in a POST, I answer the POST with a just a 200 but then my webpage goes blank.

How do I tell the browser to keep or rerender the original page? Do I need to send an HTML response to the POST? Something other than a 200?

Comment: "How do i tell the browser to keep or rerender the original page?" You cannot. Dead simple. You must respond with whatever you would like to be displayed.

Comment: @Volker So after the POST, just send the HTML I want displayed?

Comment: "How do I tell the browser to keep or rerender the original page?" -- You don't. This is the reason SPAs are popular.

Comment: "How do I tell the browser to keep or rerender the original page?"  Redirect to the page from the POST handler.  For example: `http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Volker pointed out what needed to change. The POST needed to be answered by the HTML I wanted displayed, so the real simple way to fix this is:

```
func MainPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) //get request method

    if r.Method == http.MethodPost {
        r.ParseForm()
        ...
    }

  if r.Method == "GET" || r.Method == "POST" {
        t, err := template.New("RTL Page").Parse(page)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = t.Execute(w, State)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is the basic operation of HTTP. The client sends a request, and the server responds to the request. If the client is a browser, the browser displays the response.

For GET request, browser sends the GET request to the server, the server responds with an HTML page, and browser displays it.

For POST request, browser sends the POST request along with the values submitted in the form, and the server should respond with an HTML page, so the browser can dispay it. The response displayed will be a POST response, so if you reload that page, it will try to resubmit the form.